# Ruby on Rails: Permission denied - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 80 (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

#### Steps to reproduce

1. I created my database and migrated.
2. I ran `rails server`.

This was the result:

```
[3957] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[3957] * Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Russell's Teapot
[3957] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
    [3957] * Environment: development
    [3957] * Process workers: 4
    [3957] * Preloading application
    [3957] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:80
    Exiting
    Traceback (most recent call last):
            22: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
            21: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
            20: from /home/my_username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
            19: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
            18: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
            17: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
            16: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
            15: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
            14: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
            13: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
            12: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
            11: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
            10: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
             9: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:69:in `run'
             8: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:183:in `run'
             7: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:397:in `run'
             6: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:144:in `load_and_bind'
             5: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `parse'
             4: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `each'
             3: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:105:in `block in parse'
             2: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:270:in `add_tcp_listener'
             1: from /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:270:in `new'
    /home/my_usernam/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:270:in `initialize': Permission denied - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 80 (Errno::EACCES)
```

Comment: Rails listens on port 3000 by default, you may have changed some setting to get it running on port 80 instead. Regular users cannot open ports below 1024.

Comment: You'll need to use `rvmsudo` or equivalent to bind to a port below 1024.

Comment: ```rvmsudo rails s -p 80
rvmsudo: command not found```

Comment: I think its because I installed with rbenv

Answer (score 1):

Configure puma to use a different port.

```
# config/puma.rb
port(ENV.fetch('PORT', 3000))
```

In production set `PORT=80`, and in local development `unset PORT`.

> Rails listens on port 3000 by default, you may have changed some setting to get it running on port 80 instead. Regular users cannot open ports below 1024. – meagar♦

```
Permission denied - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 80 (Errno::EACCES)
```

Only `root` can bind ports below 1024. Do not run your local development server as `root`! Instead, configure a port above 1024.

Comment: Hmm, adding that line into my config file didn't change the end result.

Comment: Check your envirnoment variables eg. `::Rails.logger.info('My port is set to: ' + ENV['PORT'])`